# Do US politicians issue UK-style manifestos?

Tags: united-states, election, united-kingdom

In the UK, political parties publish manifestos that go into reasonable detail about their plans post-election. Naturally, as politicians, they don't always deliver on their promises, but at least it provides a basis for calling them to account.

From what I can tell, the situation in the US is very different, and during a campaign policies appear to be made up on the spot, then reversed if they don't get the right reaction.

**Do US politicians publish manifestos, or provide something similar?**

UK examples:

- https://www.conservatives.com/manifesto
- http://www.ukip.org/manifesto2015
- http://www.labour.org.uk/manifesto (which appears to allow you to pick and choose which policies you want to read)
- http://www.libdems.org.uk/read-the-full-manifesto

Answer (score 7):

On a party level, "manifesto" is called a "Platform" in US.

Specific example: https://www.gop.com/platform/ , https://www.democrats.org/party-platform

A collection of all (or a large amount) of platforms: http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/platforms.php

---

Specific candidates issue piecemail position views, including their planned budgets. Here's [a coverage of Hillary Clinton's one](http://useconomy.about.com/od/fiscalpolicy/p/Hillary_Economy.htm) (from surface scan, seems to be an uncritical cheerleading piece from Clinton's supporter, so don't take it for impartial analysis). Here's [Donald Trump's budget ideas from the horse's mouth](https://www.donaldjtrump.com/positions/tax-reform).

Comment: Thanks, it was the 'common language' divide stumping me.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to party platforms, it has become traditional for each major U.S. presidential candidate to publish a book during their campaign.  This book typically highlights topics that the candidate wants to make improvements in.  Some typical examples:

- *[Putting People First](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0812921933)*, by Bill Clinton and Al Gore in 1992.
- *[United We Stand](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000OL89RQ)*, by Ross Perot in 1992.
- *[Stronger Together](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01JMECLZQ)*, by Hilary Clinton and Tim Kaine in 2016.
- *[Great Again](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1501138006)*, by Donald Trump in 2016.